# Php file upload strange behaviour, occasionally upload is empty

Tags: php, file-upload, http-post, createfile, read-write

I use this script to upload files via POST from my android app to my server. 95% of the time it works ok, but sometimes the upload folder of my clients is empty. The file is sent definitely,  because I get the name and phone numbers (without a file selected the app will not pass any data), but the uploaded file is not written to disk on the server. I am not an expert in php, maybe I have missed something:

My upload php script:

```
$file_path = "uploads/{$_POST['name']}/";

if (!file_exists("uploads/{$_POST['name']}")) {
    mkdir("uploads/{$_POST['name']}", 0777, true);  
} else {
    echo 'folder already exists!';
}


$newfile = $_POST['name'] . "_" . date('m-d_H-i-s') . '.zip';
$filename = $file_path . $newfile;

if(!file_exists($filename)) {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['zipFile']['tmp_name'], $filename)) {
    echo "success";
    }
 } else  {
    echo 'file already exists';
 }
```

Comment: Does it echo `success` when this happens?

Comment: @Bramar i don't really see that happen, it is running in the background in the moment of the upload. Maybe I should send the echo about success/faliure via mail, temporarily.

Comment: After you submit the form, it should refresh the page and show whatever the script echoed. Try adding `else { echo "move_uploaded_file failed"; }` to the inner `if`.